TikZ: Automatically get a good bounding box: reset the origin
The tikzpicture appears to automatically include the (0,0) coordinate, even though the coordinates that are used only extend between x-values 1970 and 2028. Below I can crop the bounding box with a scope and clip, but it would be more convenient to have a global setting in the preamble.
Perhaps reset the x-value origin to be 1970? thus keeping the convenience of using actual dates like 1973 in the code: I do not want to manually subtract 1970 every time I define a new coordinate.
Also: I do NOT want to use pgfplots.
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{>=latex}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01cm, y=1cm]

% coordinate Origin
\coordinate (O) at (1970,0);

% coordinate End
\coordinate (F) at (2028,0);

% fix the problem
\begin{scope}% I do not want this

\clip  (1970,-2) rectangle (2028,+2);% I do not want this

% fill a rectangle
\fill [color=red!50] rectangle (1973,0) -- (2025,0) -- (2025,2) -- (1973,2);

% draw the horizontal timeline with arrow
\draw[->] (O) -- (F);

\end{scope}% I do not want this

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Desired Result:

Actual Result:


I've had to tweak the units, e.g. \tikzset{x=0.2cm, y=1cm}, getting a dimensions too large error/crash when I don't get it right the first time.

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01cm, y=1cm,trim left= (O)] should work.

That's a great one to know, thanks Ulrike!

@UlrikeFischer that just corrects the effects of the erroneous use of rectangle rather than correcting the error.

trim left= (O) is a great one to know though, because sometimes constructing figures with circles and intersections does extend beyond the desired limits.

@PatrickT that is absolutely true. but it isn't the right way to solve the problem in this particular question, imho.

You are misusing rectangle. The syntax is:
... (<corner coordinate>) rectangle (<opposite corner coordinate>) ...

So,
\fill rectangle (1973,0) -- (2025,0) -- (2025,2) -- (1973,2);

first specifies a rectangular region from the default coordinate ((0,0)) to (1973,0) and then constructs a path from (1973,0) to (1973,2) via the intermediate coordinates.
To see what's happening, add draw,
    \fill [color=red!50, draw=blue] rectangle (1973,0) -- (2025,0) -- (2025,2) -- (1973,2);


Note that not only is the path from the origin shown. You can also see that one side of the rectangle has an undrawn border because we didn't draw the line from (1973,2) to (1973,0) i.e. this path is open.
If you use rectangle properly, you can see that tikz does not add the origin unless it is used (implicitly or explicitly) in the tikzpicture specification.
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{>=latex}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01cm, y=1cm]
  % coordinate Origin
  \coordinate (O) at (1970,0);
  % coordinate End
  \coordinate (F) at (2028,0);
    % fill a rectangle
    \fill [color=red!50] (1973,0) rectangle (2025,2);

    % draw the horizontal timeline with arrow
    \draw[->] (O) -- (F);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}



Oh! excellent. I hadn't noticed the issue! Thank you!
